# How to correctly emit values to Sink from multiple Fluxes (WebsocketSession::receive) in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-websocket

In my simplified case I want to broadcast a message sent by WebSocket client to all other clients. The application is built using reactive websockets with Spring.

My idea was to use single
`Sink` and if a message is received from the client, emit it on this sink. `WebsocketSession::send` just forwards events emitted by this `Sink` to connected clients.

```
@Component
class ReactiveWebSocketHandler(private val sink: Sinks.Many<Message>,
                               private val objectMapper : ObjectMapper) : WebSocketHandler {

    override fun handle(session: WebSocketSession): Mono<Void> {

        val input = session.receive()
                .doOnNext {
                    sink.emitNext(fromJson(it.payloadAsText, Message::class.java), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
                }
                .then()
        val output = session.send(sink.asFlux().map { message -> session.textMessage(toJson(message)) })

        return Mono.zip(input, output).then()
    }

    fun toJson(obj : Any) : String = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)

    fun <T> fromJson(json : String, clazz : Class<T>) : T{
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz)
    }

}
```

This implementation is not safe as `Sink.emitNext` can be called from different threads.

My attempt was to use `publishOn` and pass a singled threaded `Scheduler` so that `onNext` for all `WebSocketSession`s is called from a single thread. However
this does not work. One item is emitted from a websocket client and then all subsequent websocket clients receive onClose event immediately after connection :

```
@Component
class ReactiveWebSocketHandler(private val sink: Sinks.Many<Message>,
                               private val objectMapper : ObjectMapper) : WebSocketHandler {

    private val scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("sink-scheduler")

    override fun handle(session: WebSocketSession): Mono<Void> {

        val input = session.receive()
                .publishOn(scheduler) // publish on single threaded scheduler
                .doOnNext {
                    sink.emitNext(fromJson(it.payloadAsText, Message::class.java), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
                }
                .then()
        ...
    }

}
```

Another option which I could see is to `synchronize` on some common lock so that emission is thread safe :

```
@Component
class ReactiveWebSocketHandler(private val sink: Sinks.Many<Message>,
                               private val objectMapper : ObjectMapper) : WebSocketHandler {

    private val lock = Any()

    override fun handle(session: WebSocketSession): Mono<Void> {

        val input = session.receive()
                .doOnNext {
                    synchronized(lock) {
                        sink.emitNext(fromJson(it.payloadAsText, Message::class.java), Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
                    }
                }
                .then()
        ...
    }


}
```

However I am not sure if this should be done like that.

#### The question is

Is it possible to use `publishOn` in this case so that emission is thread safe and if not what is other solution to this problem (apart of using synchronization like I have done with `synchronized` keyword).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of pessimistic locking with the `synchronized` option, you could create an `EmitFailureHandler` comparable to `FAIL_FAST` except it returns `true` for `EmitResult.NON_SERIALIZED_ACCESS`.

This would result in the concurrent emit attempts to be immediately retried, like in a busy loop.

Optimistically, this will end up succeeding. You can even make the custom handler introduce a delay or limit the number of times it returns `true` if you want to be extra defensive against infinite loops.

Comment: Great, I will give it a try. Do you happen to know why when I use `publishOn` with single threaded scheduler before `onNext` - one message is emitted to `Sink` and then all subsequent websocket connections receive onClose event imediatelly? In a simple standalone app such setup also fixes the problem but in case of websockets - it fails.

Comment: @michalk emitNext is hard-coded to terminate the subscribers with an error if concurrent access is detected. tryEmitNext is an alternative lower level api that give you more control in that regard, but you'll have to account for each possible return value (an enum). the emitFailureHandler is kind of a middle ground

Comment: @SimonBaslé "You can even make the custom handler introduce a delay" - wouldn't this potentially block some important thread? or waiting can be so short that it does not have too much impact?

Comment: @SimonBaslé what is the Sinks.Many API equivalent of SerializedFluxSink? I used to obtain these via FluxProcessor.sink() and I am missing this feature in the new API.

Comment: `Sinks.many` are protected against concurrent usage, but they fail fast instead of trying to be too smart.The previous approach was to put events in a queue and drain it from a single thread, but that could be problematic.  since the tryEmit APIs return a result, this isn't even an option anymore (you could get an ack of eg. an `onNext` while you just tried to do `tryEmitComplete`).

Comment: The EmitFailureHandler.busyLooping method does exactly this and is added in 2022 to project reactor: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.html#busyLooping-java.time.Duration-

Answer (score 4):

In additon to the @simon-baslé answer here is the sample code (for srping-webflux). It will downstream the request to the subscriber and in case of `Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED` response will retry.
This is the `Sinks.EmitFailureHandler` definition:

```
private final Sinks.EmitFailureHandler emitFailureHandler = (signalType, emitResult) -> emitResult
            .equals(Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED) ? true : false;
```

Here are the controller which will handle the request:

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

    private final Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
    private final Sinks.EmitFailureHandler emitFailureHandler = (signalType, emitResult) -> emitResult
            .equals(Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED) ? true : false;
    @Autowired
    public RestController(ServiceSubscriber serviceSubscriber) {
        sink.asFlux().subscribe(serviceSubscriber);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> getData(@PathVariable String id) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            sink.emitNext(id, emitFailureHandler);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().<Void>build();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The publishOn a single threaded scheduler approach should work but you need to use the same scheduler instance for each `ReactiveWebSocketHandler`.

Can you rather combine all of the receive() Fluxes using a flatMap rather than using the Sink?

My own solution to this problem takes the busy spin approach [suggested by Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202495/2949876).

See my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65185325/2949876).