# Reactor - handle FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED error from a Many sink

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have created a `Many` sink into which I produce items from multiple threads:

```java
Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();

// below just dummy code to simulate parallel producer
Flux.range(1, 1000)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .doOnNext(t -> {
            sink.emitNext(t, (signal, failure) -> {
                System.out.println(failure);
                return failure == Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED;
            });
        })
        .sequential()
        .count()
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .block();
```

By default the sink does not allow emitting items to it parallelly from many threads and throws a `Sinks$EmissionException` and states that `Spec. Rule 1.3 - onSubscribe, onNext, onError and onComplete signaled to a Subscriber MUST be signaled serially.`. Fortunately, the Reactor library offers a way to handle this so I can pass an `EmitFailureHandler` to the `emitNext` method which is basically a `BiPredicate` in which I can define whether I would like Reactor to retry emission. In the above example the code retries emission every time it encounters this failure.

Is this correct way of handling this error? Is there any drawback like retries exhausting CPU or potential deadlock? Is there a more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186439/how-to-correctly-emit-values-to-sink-from-multiple-fluxes-websocketsessionrec) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65029619/how-to-call-sinks-manyt-tryemitnext-from-multiple-threads). Might be related.

Comment: Thanks! Those kind of answer my question.