# Too many retries when using Sinks.Many<T>.tryEmitNext from multiple threads

Tags: java, project-reactor

Based on @Simon Baslé suggestion from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202495/15636190
I implemented this retry mechanism.

```
Sinks.EmitResult result;
while ((result = sink.tryEmitNext(object)) == Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED) {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(10);
}
```

In my tests I see that 30% requests fail with NON_SERIALIZED.
If I count how many times retry happens it gives average of 30 retries per single failed request until it eventually succeeds.
Is it expected to be that many?

Comment: Did you consider randomizing the delay?